# does meteor ccorcos/meteor-transitioner package provides swipe feature for mobile

Tags: javascript, meteor, transition

I am building a mobile app in meteor and need this feature, when the user swipes (say left|right|top|down|), it should hit the iron router and then the router should display a another template.

So can this functionality be achieved by this package 
https://github.com/ccorcos/meteor-transitioner

Or are there any good packages that does this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that package is for animation/transition effects between pages.  The package you need for your stated purpose is called 'Hammer' by Chris Wessels:

https://atmospherejs.com/chriswessels/hammer

I've successfully implemented a long-press with this package; it supports many other gestures including swiping, and I found it pretty easy to implement.